# If no circuit then unique vertex basis

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Show the vertex basis in a directed graph is unique if there is no sequence of directed edges that forms a circuit in the graph.

Is this right? Or I should provide more explanation

Let A and B be two different vertex basis of graph G. Since A is vertex basis, then there exists some directed path that takes a vertex a' in A to a vertex b' in B. Similarly, there is a directed path taking vertex b' to a'. Contradiction since this creates a circuit a'-x1-x2....-xn-b'y1-y2-.....yn-a'

Comment: What is the vertex basis?

Answer (score 2):

To begin, the definition of a vertex basis is:

> A vertex basis is a set of vertices where there’s a path to every vertex outside this set from vertices of this set, and there’s no path from any vertex in the set to another vertex in the set.  ([Source](http://furthermathematicst.blogspot.com.au/2011/07/102-paths-cycles.html))

Regarding the proposed proof, this is not necessarily true:

> *Similarly, there is a directed path taking vertex $b'$ to $a'$*

since $a'$ and $b'$ have been determined.  All we know is that there is a path from *some* vertex $v \in B$ to $a'$ (and maybe $v \neq b'$).

To prove the claim:

- We conjecture that the unique vertex basis will be the set of all vertices of in-degree $0$.  It immediately follows that this is a subset of any vertex basis.
- Suppose a vertex $v$ of in-degree $\geq 1$ is in a hypothetical vertex basis.  We walk backwards (i.e., against the edge direction) until either (a) we reach a vertex with in-degree $0$ (which is in the vertex basis, giving a contradiction) or (b) we reach a vertex we've seen before (which gives rise to a circuit).